# What is the status of long-running remote R sessions in ESS/Emacs?

Tags: r, session, emacs, tmux, ess

I routinely run R remotely and have had great success with RStudio server to do so.  However, Emacs/ESS is still preferable in many cases, particularly since I often work on multiple projects simultaneously.  What is the start-of-the-art when running ESS/R in emacs when the expectation is that the connection will be broken?  To be more concrete, I'd love to run a tmux session in Emacs so that I can connect to a long-running R session running in tmux (or screen).  What is the status of ESS/Emacs to support such a scenario?  This seems to be changing over time and I haven't found the "definitive" approach (perhaps there isn't one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do that all the time.  At both home, and work.

Key components:

1. Start emacs in daemon mode:  `emacs --daemon &`. Now emacs is long-running and persistent as it is disconnected from the front-end.
2. Connect using `emacsclient -nw` in text mode using tmux (or in my case, the byobu wrapper around tmux). As tmux persists, I can connect, disconnect, reconnect,... at will while having several tabs, split panes, ... from byobu/tmux.
3. When nearby -- on home desktop connecting to home server, or at work with several servers -- connect via `emacsclient -c`. Now I have the standard X11 goodness, plotting etc pp.  That is my default 'working' mode.
4. But because each emacs session has an R session (or actually several, particularly at work) I can actually get to them as I can ssh into the tmux/byobu session too.
5. Another nice feature is tramp-mode allowing you to edit a remote file (possibly used by a remote R session) in a local Emacs buffer as tramp wraps around ssh and scp making the remote file appear local.
6. Last but not least mosh is very nice on the (Ubuntu) laptop as it automagically resumes sessions when I am back on the local network at home or work.  In my case mosh from Debian/Ubuntu on server and client; may also work for you OS X folks.

In short, works like a dream, but may require the extra step of "disconnecting" emacs from the particularly tmux shell in which you launch. Daemon mode is key. Some of these sessions run on for weeks.

I started working like this maybe half a decade ago. Possibly longer.  But using ESS to connect to remote Emacs session is much older -- I think the ESS manual already had entries for it when I first saw it in the late 1990s.

But I find this easier as it gives me "the whole emacs" including whatever other buffers and session I may need.

**Edit:** And just to be plain, I also use RStudio (Server) at home and work, but generally spend more time in Emacs for all the usual reasons.

**More Edits:** In follow-up to [@kjhealy](https://twitter.com/kjhealy/status/580150117564571649) I added that I am also a fan of both tramp-mode (edit remote files locally in Emacs thanks to the magic that are ssh and scp) as well as mosh (sessions that magically resume when I get to work or back home).

Comment: It would be so nice if ess-remote could connect to R process not started by emacs. Then tramp mode could do everything for you.